# How can I cancel setInterval running with global variable?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to clear/stop `setInterval` from running, and have made changes to my approach based on other questions/answers I've found, but still can't get `setInterval` to stop running.

What I have here, is a Mutation Observer which detects a class change, and when that occurs, if two conditions are true (the presence of other classes), then some cursor tracking executes. All this works great.

When one of the two classes, `.run-preview`, is removed I then want to stop `setInterval` from running, as seen in the `else if`. I also have a commented line there where I was verifying that the `else if` is working, and it is.

I have a global variable `intervalCursor = setInterval(move,1000/60);`, and then am using that variable to later `clearInterval(intervalCursor);`.

```js
const runPreview = document.querySelector('.projects');

new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  if (mutations[0].attributeName === 'class') {
    console.log('Project list class changed');
 
    if ($('html').hasClass('no-touchevents') && ($('.projects').hasClass('run-preview'))) {
    
        var mouseX=window.innerWidth/2,
            mouseY=window.innerHeight/2;
        var intervalCursor = setInterval(move,1000/60);
            
        var projectPreview = {
         el:$('.image-container'),
         x:window.innerWidth/2, 
         y:window.innerHeight/2, 
         w:300,
         h:300, 
         update:function() {
           l = this.x-this.w/2; 
           t = this.y-this.h/2; 
           this.el.css({ 
            'transform':
            'translate3d('+l+'px,'+t+'px, 0)' });
            //console.log("transform");
           }
        }
        
        $(window).mousemove (function(e){
          mouseX = e.clientX;
          mouseY = e.clientY;
          //console.log("mousemove");
        })
        
        
        function move(){
          projectPreview.x = lerp (projectPreview.x, mouseX, 0.1);
          projectPreview.y = lerp (projectPreview.y, mouseY, 0.1);
          projectPreview.update() 
          console.log("move");
        }
        
        function lerp (start, end, amt){
          return (1-amt)*start+amt*end
        }

    } else if (!$('.projects').hasClass('run-preview')) {
        clearInterval(intervalCursor);
        return;
        //$('#content-container').addClass('test');
    }
 
  }
})

.observe(runPreview, { attributes: true });
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From the code you show, `intervalCursor` isn't global.

Comment: Oh? Maybe it's my misunderstanding of the scope. I thought that it not being specifically tied to `function move()` that it wasn't local.

Comment: It is visible to the particular instance of `move()`, it's just not global. `intervalCursor` is created anew each time `MutationObserver`'s anonymous function is called. (Every time a relevant mutation happens.) The variable may have the same name, but it's a new instance on every call. You'll need to give the variable a larger scope in order to use it the way you are. Create it outside of the anonymous function.

Comment: Yes that was it! I wasn't making the connection with the `Mutation Observer`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ouroborus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367865/ouroborus), I was able to solve this by creating the variable separately from the `MutationObserver`, and then using it to run `setInterval(move,1000/60);` later. Thus allowing `setInterval` to be cleared/stopped when I need to.

```js
var intervalCursor

const runPreview = document.querySelector('.projects');

new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  if (mutations[0].attributeName === 'class') {
    console.log('Project list class changed');
 
    if ($('html').hasClass('no-touchevents') && ($('.projects').hasClass('run-preview'))) {
    
        var mouseX=window.innerWidth/2,
            mouseY=window.innerHeight/2;
            
        var projectPreview = {
         el:$('.image-container'),
         x:window.innerWidth/2, 
         y:window.innerHeight/2, 
         w:300,
         h:300, 
         update:function() {
           l = this.x-this.w/2; 
           t = this.y-this.h/2; 
           this.el.css({ 
            'transform':
            'translate3d('+l+'px,'+t+'px, 0)' });
            //console.log("transform");
           }
        }
        
        $(window).mousemove (function(e){
          mouseX = e.clientX;
          mouseY = e.clientY;
          //console.log("mousemove");
        })
        
        
        intervalCursor = setInterval(move,1000/60);
        function move(){
          projectPreview.x = lerp (projectPreview.x, mouseX, 0.1);
          projectPreview.y = lerp (projectPreview.y, mouseY, 0.1);
          projectPreview.update() 
          console.log("move");
        }
        
        function lerp (start, end, amt){
          return (1-amt)*start+amt*end
        }

    } else if (!$('.projects').hasClass('run-preview')) {
        clearInterval(intervalCursor);
        //$('#content-container').addClass('test');
    }
 
  }
})

.observe(runPreview, { attributes: true });
```